# Square Grid - XML

Tags: android, xml, grid

In my studies, I have to do an Android application that retrieves weather data from a weather station. These will be displayed in blocks.
These blocks will depart on 4 columns and 2 rows.

[image]

So I wanted to create a square grid of 4 columns and 2 lines for the provision of the blocks.

Someone would have a solution to help me create this grid, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many options :
1. you can choose a recycler view with GridLayoutManager

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
  android:id="@+id/main_grid"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:padding="2dp"
  />
```

So inside activity you will do something like

```
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), COLUMN_COUNT));
```

2. You choose grid view

```
<GridView
android:id="@+id/grid"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
android:horizontalSpacing="2dp"
android:numColumns="4"
android:padding="4dp"
android:stretchMode="columnWidth"/>
```

For fixed item size you should use

```
<android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  app:columnCount="4"
  app:orientation="horizontal"
  >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    />
  <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    />

</android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>
```

Make sure you add this in your app gradle

```
compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:23.0.1'
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! I prefer choose the XML, so the GridView. With this, I can get my square grid?

Comment: I want a grid, for design block. Let me explain. I would like a grid of lines 2 and 4 columns. I would also expect to benefit from a grid to distinguish the 2 lines and 4 blocks initially. Do you have a solution to my problem please?

Comment: Did you try it? I think it should work. You might need to force your orientation of the view in landscape mode.. Rest should work fine!

Comment: Yes I have try it. But, it's not good. Maybe use a TableLayout and TableRow?

Comment: Can you explain what's not good? What's your item looks like?

Comment: I draw on this picture, the design of my grid. Juste a square grid, looks like the first picture in the first post for the moment. No more.

Comment: The rows are not fixed in order to match the design you want you have to give fix height to your item..

Comment: I just want a grid, like a table with two rows and four columns, nothing more.

Comment: Yes in order to do that you either have to set a android:minHeight for your item or you can set a fixed height for your entire item.

Comment: Thanks but any changes in my GridView with this params.

Comment: Is your item count fixed?

Comment: The grid is and will be fixed forever. So, yes the item is and will be fixed.

Comment: I test now your solution

Comment: No grid view is for dynamic item size if you have fixed item size you can set your item like i have textviews in my support grid layout

Comment: Android Studio can't initialised the GridLayout

Comment: Did you add the dependency in your app gradle under dependencies section?

Comment: A last question : Is it possible to resize the grid with 4 columns and 2 rows?

Comment: What do you mean by resizing? Do you wanna add more items or you just want to scale your items?

Comment: A grid by default create a lot of columns and rows. So, I want to know if it's possible to resize this grid, and get my square grid

Comment: If you give fixed height and width to your items in grid layout you should have something like a square..

Comment: The grid is composed by four blocs aligned horizontal in one ligne and below four other square